# Including only changed files in minor upgrade msi?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I made a minor upgrade package that includes only changed files excluding the files remaining the same as those in the original package. But, because it's not formally supported way to make a minor upgrade package I don't know I can continue to make minor upgrade package in this way without any side effect.

I want to get some ideas on the expected side effects of using this package as a minor upgrade. I want to reduce the size of minor upgrade package as small as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Please see the help topic: [Creating patches](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/patching.htm)

Comment: AFAIK a patch is not applicable when product version is changed. If I had changed product version, is there no way but to provide full package as a minor upgrade?

Comment: Change the fourth field.

Comment: Then a change in the product that merely deserves changing the third field of product version must be delivered by full package regardless of its size(measured by diff. between two packages)? I wonder if there is any other method for these 'middle' cases.

Comment: I'd post your question on the wix-users mailing list.  Blair Murri is the man when it comes to patching.